# What's the math behind generators with electromagnet cores?

Tags: power-supply

Our biggest generators spin an electromagnet to produce current. Why does it take less electricity to maintain the electromagnet than the electromagnet generates? In an ideal world, how much power would it take to maintain the electromagnet?

Comment: I voted to close this  because the question is vague.  "Maintain what? Power vs what( B or H or Torque)? Show the detail reference or link to your misunderstanding of EM and energy conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it take less electricity to maintain the electromagnet than the electromagnet generates?

Why not? The two are mostly unrelated - the amount of power to run the electromagnet is determined by resistive losses, while the power generated is mostly dependent on speed of rotation.

> In an ideal world, how much power would it take to maintain the electromagnet?

Theoretically an electromagnet made of superconductors can be maintained with zero input power. Currently this is only used in MRI machines, which need a very high field strength, because the superconductors have to be kept very cold.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields don't transfer energy per se. Otherwise we would be able to power our civilization from the earth's poles. It is a *changing* magnetic field that can transfer energy.

In a generator, it is the relative motion of the rotor field as it moves past the stator that produces a changing magnetic field in the stator coils. This change is produced by the mechanical movement of the rotor, driven by whatever is turning the generator, and it follows that this is where the energy source for the generator comes from.

You could actually 'power' the generator by instead locking the rotor and varying the rotor coil field (by modulating the current). In that situation the energy coming out of the generator would indeed be entirely sourced from the rotor electromagnet. In a simpler form, this is known as a transformer.